# Display Viewbag in .cshtml form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display @ViewBag.Name on my .cshml form field.

Tried this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "@ViewBag.Name" } })
```

But only displays raw data. Eg. @ViewBag.Name

The source code looks like this.

```
<input Value="@ViewBag.Name" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
```

Can anyone help? thank you!

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `@ViewBag.Name`.  You're using a string literal.

Comment: Amy is right, you should also consider passing this in the model instead of relying on the `ViewBag`.

Comment: Under no circumstances do you set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. Set the value of the `Name` property in your GET method before you pass the model to he view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove value="" from you code.You need to write code as shown below.

```
<input value="@ViewBag.Name" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
```

this will display your viewbag value as befault value for your textbox

Comment: Terrible advice.